# Wi-fi gets disconnected automatically Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: 16.04, asus, realtek-wireless

Wi-fi gets disconnected automatically in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. Disabling and Re-enabling the wi-fi doesn't work until I reboot.

```
$ sudo lshw -class network command is:
description: Ethernet interface
   product: RTL8101/2/6E PCI Express Fast/Gigabit Ethernet controller
   vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
   physical id: 0.2
   bus info: pci@0000:02:00.2
   logical name: enp2s0f2
   version: 06
   serial: 70:8b:cd:d2:3a:42
   size: 10Mbit/s
   capacity: 100Mbit/s
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd autonegotiation
   configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=half firmware=rtl8402-1_0.0.1 10/26/11 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII speed=10Mbit/s
   resources: irq:48 ioport:5000(size=256) memory:9b210000-9b210fff memory:c2100000-c2103fff
  *-network
       description: Wireless interface
       product: RTL8723BE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       logical name: wlp3s0
       version: 00
       serial: 74:df:bf:fd:84:88
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rtl8723be driverversion=4.4.0-64-generic firmware=N/A ip=172.17.8.197 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bgn
       resources: irq:19 ioport:4000(size=256) memory:9b100000-9b103fff
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest upgrading the kernel. I have exactly same wireless adapter that works well with the 4.8 kernel.

Run in a terminal

```
sudo apt install linux-generic-hwe-16.04
```

and reboot.

Comment: Thanks a lot for replying. It helped me with Wi-fi issue. But after updating the kernel, my touch-pad clicking stopped working. I have to boot with older kernel version through grub while booting. How can i roll back to my previous kernel version permanently? Current kernel version(after upgrading)--   4.8.0-39 generic .   Previous Kernel version--   4.4.0-64 generic.

Comment: The touchpad issue can be very easily fixed. Ask a new question for that. libinput config file has changed.